# Proto Unmarshall a map[string]some stuct

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, unmarshalling, grpc-go

I have a requirement where I need to proto.Unmarshal a map<string, ABVariantEntries> where ABVariantEntries is a struct
I am trying below approaches but none of them work. Kindly let me know what would be the correct way

```
styleVariants := make(map[string]*style_fetch.ABVariantEntries)
proto.Unmarshal([]byte(value), &styleVariants)// gives `cannot use &styleVariants (value of type *map[string]*style_fetch.ABVariantEntries) as protoiface.MessageV1 value in argument to proto.Unmarshal: *map[string]*style_fetch.ABVariantEntries does not implement protoiface.MessageV1 `
```

```
styleVariants := map[string]*style_fetch.ABVariantEntries{}
proto.Unmarshal([]byte(value), &styleVariants)// gives `cannot use &styleVariants (value of type *map[string]*style_fetch.ABVariantEntries) as protoiface.MessageV1 value in argument to proto.Unmarshal: *map[string]*style_fetch.ABVariantEntries does not implement protoiface.MessageV1`
```

I had to instead define another strict on top of below proto, and use struct StyleVariant

```
message StyleVariant {
  map<string, ABVariantEntries> style_variants = 1;
}
```

```
styleVariants := &style_fetch.StyleVariant{}
proto.Unmarshal([]byte(value), styleVariants)
```

Is there a way to directly use `map<string, ABVariantEntries>` in proto.Unmarshal and not define another struct on top of it?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: This message is not really a struct, it is a part of the protocol buffer mechanism. A message is the interface to proto. Before handing something to proto it needs to be put in a message, so you can not use a struct directly with proto.